# Previews cannot be hosted inside "com.apple.keyboard-service" app extensions

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am writing **SwiftUI** views into **keyboard extention** (into UIkit views).

In extention module swftui previews do not work, and complaining with **"Previews cannot be hosted inside 'com.apple.keyboard-service' app extensions"**

Is there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: Move SwiftUI part into separated swift package, Preview now works for packages.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue, and I had a workaround. Here's what I did:

When I created the new SwiftUI file, I added it to both targets (main app and keyboard extension). Though I would not use it in main app target, the preview showed.

Comment: Have you tried to switch the scheme to your main app?